# Does PicturePark integrate with Basecamp?

Tags: asset-management

So we're getting our new DAM [PicturePark](https://picturepark.com/) populated with all of our digital assets, but one thing that I can't seem to find any obvious documentation on is how to integrate it with our project management software [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/).

We're operating under the impression that it *does* integrate, but there are doubts spreading through the office that the product won't deliver as it was expected to.

Anyone here use picture PicturePark? Have you had any success integrating it with a project management application so your designers can put up their files through the PM?

Comment: Hi ShemSeger, welcome to the site! Did you try contacting PicturePark's support?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge on PicturePark but you can check the programs that already integrate with BaseCamp https://basecamp.com/extras. PicturePark would have more information if they are using BootCamps API.